# Como chamar uma função no clique do Input Type = "date"

Tags: javascript, html5, input, data, input-type-date

Amigos, tenho uma questão que ficaria feliz se pudessem me ajudar.

Eu tenho um calendário criado com o `<input type="date">` do *Html5*.
Eu preciso que ao clicar em uma data específica ele pegue o valor da data e chame uma função *PHP* que vai carregar uma nova página passando como parâmetro a data que foi clicada para esta função PHP.

Eu consigo fazer isso com um botão porque passo como parâmetro na variável global `$_GET` chamando um *PHP* que vai receber esta informação, mas preciso que seja feita sem o botão *submit* do *form*, e sim ao clicar da data. Alguém sabe como proceder?????

Comment: Para ativar quando a data mudar podes usar o evento `change`, podes mostrar o código que já tens com um botão?

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e coloque os códigos que já tentou. Facilitará a ajuda

Comment: Não é tão simples assim, o evento OnChange que vc mencionou é acionado antes dele preencher a nova data na input. Portanto após chamar o onchange ele preenche a data da input. Como vou saber o valor da input (ou da data) se ele é acionado antes dele preencher a data?

Comment: @MarceloJoséLustosaRodrigues o change vem depois de escolher a data. Dá uma olhada aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/0thw8coh/1/

Comment: @MarceloJoséLustosaRodrigues se alguma destas respostas solucionou o teu problema podes marcar essa como aceite.

Answer (score 1):

Tens vários eventos à escolha o `input` e `change` servem para o que queres. O `blur` também, mas só dispara quando clicares fora do `input`.

Exemplo:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var mostrador = document.getElementById('mostrador');

input.addEventListener('input', log);
input.addEventListener('change', log);
input.addEventListener('focus', log);
input.addEventListener('blur', log);

var contador = 0;

function log(e) {
  mostrador.innerHTML = [
    contador++,'|', e.type, this.value || 'sem valor',
    '<br>' + mostrador.innerHTML
  ].join(' ');
}
```

```css
#mostrador {
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="mostrador"></div>

<input type="date">
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o evento da tag chamado : onchange
No caso ficaria assim:

```
<input id="Testes" type="date" onchange="alert(this.value)" >
```

aí você utilizaria um método javascript para analisar o valor e dentro desse javascript você poderia no caso fazer uma camada para o seu PHP.
Eu não tenho tanta prática em PHP, porém, acredito que você possa colocar código PHP dentro de script.

Caso não possa chamar código PHP... você ainda pode fazer com que esse seu método click em algum botão invisível dentro do seu código HTML e este executasse o método PHP que você deseja.

Caso não esteja confortável com as chamadas contantes quando está digitando a data e ela completa todos os valores, teste então utilizar o evento onBlur ( ele só é chamado quando o campo perde o foco.)